# How to install gem pg and mysql2 in codenvy.io / goormide.io?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg, mysql2

Log terminal:

> ```
> user@c6b65b118139:/projects/rails-jafar$ gem install pg
> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing pg:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>     current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/pg-1.1.4/ext
> /usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190831-425-ife1vi.rb extconf.rb
> checking for pg_config... no
> No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
>  --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
> checking for libpq-fe.h... no
> Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
> libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
> need configuration options.
> ```

apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

> libmysqlclient-dev E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock -
>   open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to lock the administration
>   directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: I guess you are using a system wide installation of ruby, that requires super user privileges to install gems. I strongly recommend you install ruby for the current user using rvm or rbenv so you don't mess with the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goorm.io 
I solving with install libpq-dev

```
apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

gem install mysql2
```